# Reading a CSV file and skipping some values

Tags: python, csv

I'm having trouble with reading a csv file using Python.  My current code is as follows:

```
import csv
dataFile = open ("useraccounts.csv", "r")
reader = csv.reader (dataFile)
next(reader)
for row in reader:
         if row[0] and row [1] in (None, ""):#if (row[0] and row[1]):
                print ("Error") #
         else:
                print (row [0] + row [1] )
```

What I want it to do is to read the names from the csv file (named useraccounts.csv), I want it to skip a name if it doesn't have both firstname and lastname. (if it only has a firstname and doesn't have a lastname, then it should be skipped and vice versa.) Also, all values need to be converted into lowercase, only the first letter of the firstname should be printed and the full surname, and they need to be concatenated together.

Here is an image of my csv file:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi7Kl.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Read csv with pandas instead and drop `NaN` values

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("useraccounts.csv",index_col=None).dropna()
```

`df` is your dataframe read from CSV.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I need to use import csv. Any suggestions?